# Explain the parameters in GitHub Gist raw_url attribute

Tags: github-api, gist

I am working with the GitHub GIST API. I came across `raw_url` attribute which is given for each file in a gist. I wanted to what all the parameters in the URL mean.

Example `raw_url`: `https://gist.githubusercontent.com/algomaster99/d75743336c68306f242ea7ec846f55e9/raw/243230d8f9f80320d839db1f944ac7918ffdaa68/.block`

1. `https://gist.githubusercontent.com/` - Domain from where the file content is fetched.
2. `algomaster99` - User ID
3. `d75743336c68306f242ea7ec846f55e9` - GIST ID
4. `243230d8f9f80320d839db1f944ac7918ffdaa68` - I don't know what is this for exactly.
5. `.block` - This is an optional parameter in URL. Works without it too.

Can anyone please elaborate on points `4` and `5`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Component 4 (`243230d8f9f80320d839db1f944ac7918ffdaa68`) is the revision id, a gist can have multiple revisions so you need the id to point out which revision you want to fetch.

Component 5 (`.block`) is simply the name of the file in the gist that you want to fetch. I'm not sure why the `.block` file is retrieved even if you omit it from the path, it could be that the first file is returned when no name is given.

Comment: This gist has 3 files: `.block`, `README.md` and `index.html`.
Each of them has a different parameter after `/raw/`.
You can check for `README.md`: `https://gist.githubusercontent.com/algomaster99/d75743336c68306f242ea7ec846f55e9/raw/ecf1bf8bf9108c871cc8049a5b270405b5b54fe6/README.md`
Even if I omit the name at the end, it still fetches the file. I am thinking it is not a revision id.
Also, the revision ID is defined for a complete gist or is it different for each file inside gist?

Comment: Interesting, that ID seems to be specific for that file and revision, so removing/changing the name doesn't make any difference as you pointed out.
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/algomaster99/d75743336c68306f242ea7ec846f55e9/raw/0aa24bfff3ef66ff27a509365ad586bc5c1a3c31/
and
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/algomaster99/d75743336c68306f242ea7ec846f55e9/raw/f81df2ffb0142dc3a525cd2e8d7c8999d4264611/
can be used to access the files at the specific revisions (append the filename).

Comment: so in your original question `243230d8f9f80320d839db1f944ac7918ffdaa68` points to a specific file and revision, and the name component just seems to be for documentation.
If you dig out the revision id's you still need to have the file name as the last path component to point out which file you want. And if no file is given it seems to default to the first file.